# Deploy to authenticated http svn without settings.xml

Tags: maven

I am trying to deploy to a google code mvn repository which requires username/password authentication when committing.

See: http://code.google.com/p/encryption-utils/source/browse/trunk/pom.xml

I do not have control over the build server which I would like to deploy here so I cannot change the .m2/settings.xml.
Is there any command line properties I can use during the mvn deploy to specify the username and password to use?
I do not care about the username and password being visible from the command line because I can ensure this build server is at least secured.

Is there any way I can do this without the settings.xml?

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a settings.xml to your project. In Jenkins/Hudson, simply use the following as your "Maven goals and options":

`-s settings.xml clean deploy`

Comment: Sadly this would mean I would have to check this in to be able to get it to my build server. With my source publicly available, this might be a bad idea because it would contain my password.

Comment: If you aren't providing them direct access to the version control tree, but just the source artifact, you can simply make sure the settings.xml isn't included in the sources.

An alternative would be to make a freestyle project. Add your settings in a separate module. Have the freestyle project download the settings-module and then trigger a Maven build of your other module.

Comment: Cool, okay, Ill do that second approach.